# Android timer notification across application activities

Tags: android, timer, popup

I have an application with several activities, and I have a timer I start in the first activity that is presented. The problem is this:

How can I get a reference to the current activity when the timer goes off when the activity I'm currently may not be the same as the one I started the timer.

What I actually want is to have a timer traverse all my actives, show an alert dialog when it expires and the do some stuff. But because of the way android works this seems to be impossible. Does anyone has an alternative?

I've already tried:

- Using an async task to access the ui thread, doesn'nt work if it is not created in the main ui thread.
- Can't use a Handler, my timer is in another class

What other choice do I have?

EDIT:

- I can´t change any of the activities code, the timer should be decoupled enough to function when someone plugs it in the project.
- Getting an instance of the current activity from the timer worker thread should work, since it would let me run stuff in the ui thread.

Comment: Ah, so you're doing this in a library project? If you don't have access to the Activities, it's really hard to display a dialog. That's what Notifications are for, really.

Comment: Yes indeed its a library, could I trigger a notification and open it programatically? If It can be done, how?

Answer (score 0):

Implement your timer as a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Then, implement an [observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern:

Create an interface (maybe called AlertListener) that is implemented by each Activity you want to be alerted. This interface should have a method, something like onTimerExpired(). This method should do whatever needs to be done to the activity when the timer expires.

In your timer class, also maintain a reference to the current AlertListener and a method, named something like "setCurrentActivity(AlertListener currentActivity)".

In onResume or some other method of each activity, call MyTimer.setCurrentActivity(this).

When the timer goes off, call currentActivity.onTimerExpired().